# Use a custom built lldb with Xcode

Tags: xcode, lldb

I had to build an lldb by myself because of an issue explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26829119/how-to-make-lldb-ignore-exc-bad-access-exception). As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312877/use-top-of-tree-lldb-with-xcode) back in 2013, this seems to be impossible. As of 2019, is there a way to use a self-built lldb with Xcode? Mainly for debugging C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

The swift.org fork of the lldb/llvm/clang project has the ability to build a "Custom Toolchain" that you can install into Xcode.  The swift/utils/build-toolchain script can be used to coordinate this process.  That's probably the easiest way to get Xcode to use a custom built lldb.